# django modelforms and fields

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a model with some fields and a User as a ForeignKey

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    #fields
    salesman = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
```

and a model form

```
class CustomerForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Customer
```

I want my form to validate if salesman is also entered but not on Database level. If I add the salesman field

```
class CustomerForm(ModelForm):
    salesman = forms.ModelChoiceField(required=True, queryset=User.objects.all(), widget=Select(attrs{"class":"form-control"})

    class Meta:
        model = Customer
```

will that overide the models salesman field? Must I overide save method to save the newly created field's value to the models default one? Or does django form sees the same name so of field and uses it correctly?

Comment: Yes, it overrides it.

Comment: So must i override the save method too?

Comment: Read the Note box in this section https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields

Comment: It doesn't override the models salesman field, it overrides the default **form** field for your model salesman field (to be pedantic).

Comment: Thank you all...Would it be better if i declared the foreign key to be blank=False, null=True?Tha will do the same right?

Answer (score 0):

You can redefine if `clean` method of the form:

```
class CustomerForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer

    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        cleaned_data = super(CustomerForm, self).clean(*args, **kwargs)
        salesman = cleaned_data.get('salesman')
        if salesman:
            # do something
        else:
            # you can rise form error if need
           msg = u"Salesman is required"
           self._errors["salesman"] = self.error_class([msg])
```